# Why PageStorageKey is not working if the ListView consists of FutureBuilder?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I use `PageStorageKey` to preserve the scroll progress of `ListView` within `TabBarView` which is under `NestedScrollView`. It works when using simple children as list items in the `ListView`. However if I use `FutureBuilders` as children, it stops preserving the scroll progress.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution: using `AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin` for each of the list items.

I suspect the reason is that somehow `FutureBuilder` will causes the `ListView` or individual list items to rebuild. And using `AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin` makes them stays in memory.

Though it solved the issue, I can't explain what actually happens behind the hood. So any further explanatory answers are welcomed!